# Regular expression for exactly one match

Tags: regex

I am using the following regular expression in my code editor (sublime text) in order to search for the ASP.NET comments.

```
<%--.*(\n.*)*--%>
```

I want this regular expression to stop looking any forward as soon as the first `--%>` is found. But it keeps looking until the last comment's `--%>` is found. I have got this idea that i've to use some kind of flag to make it stop as soon as the first `--%>` but I am unable to figure it out.

Can anyone please tell me how may I modify this regex?

**UPDATE**

I forgot to post some sample markup. Here it is:

```
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <%--<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">
            Close</button>
        <button id="btnAddCountry" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
            Save changes</button>--%>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="box paint_hover">
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Sale Voucher</span>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <ul id="tabExample1" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a id="lnkAddEditVoucher" href="#AddEditVoucher" data-toggle="tab">Add/Update Sale Voucher</a></li>
                    <li><a id="lnkViewVouchers" href="#ViewVouchers" data-toggle="tab">Search Sale Voucher</a></li>
                    <%--  <li><a id="lnkViewParties" href="#ViewParties" data-toggle="tab">Search Parties</a></li>--%>
                </ul>
```

I just want to match the first comment and not the second one.

Comment: fyi, you can use `(.|\n)` to match anything, including newlines. No need for the weird construct you used in your original regex :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make the `*` quantifiers non-greedy. Usually this is done by adding a `?` after them, e.g. `.*?` instead of just `.*`.

I've also simplified the regex a bit. Sublime Text supports the `(?s)` modifier at the beginning of the pattern to make the dot match even newlines:

```
(?s)<%--.*?--%>
```

If you prefer matching the newline explicitly:

```
<%--(.|\n)*?--%>
```

Comment: Formerly known as "reluctant" (+1)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the alternation may be unnecessary. If Sublime offers the `PCRE_DOTALL` modifier, the `.` will match newlines as well.

Comment: @Bohemian - Huh, did not know that, thanks. I think "reluctant" is more descriptive than "non-greedy."

Comment: @TheifMaster! Thanks but it doesn't work for the markup that I've posted please check that. Would you please check that?

Comment: @ThiefMaster Figured it might ;-) I'm always surprised by the regex support in even the most trivial environments.

Comment: Yeah apparently it does through the pattern itself. Updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you seem to have is that you use the greedy version of `.*`, which matches anything (including `--%>`). Try using `<%--.*?(\n.*?)*?--%>` instead to make it non-greedy.